# Apply Update/Insert in a Stored Javascript or View

Tags: mongodb

Goal:
Is it possibly to apply mongoDB:s insert and/or update code (code below) into a view or stored javascript?

```
db.account.insert({
A/c number: "12345746352",
first name: "Mark",
last name: "Jacobs"
});

db.account.update{
A/c number: "12345746352",
first name: "Mark",
last name: "Jacobs"
});
```

Compare to database using sql syntax code you can apply the the similar source code in a stored produce
If course, you need to apply the input data as a parameter in stored procedure. It probably be the same for MongoDB.

Info:
*I'm new in MongoDB

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

do you mean,

does MongoDB support stored procedures like SQL?

[Stored Javascript functions on server](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/)

Here is the [article](http://dirolf.com/2010/04/05/stored-javascript-in-mongodb-and-pymongo.html) related to that.